# Cómo ver los datos de la matrix en bytes en lugar de char?

Tags: java

No tengo idea de como ver los datos que escribo por teclado de otra manera que no sea en código ascii ya que se almacenan en char por el método read, gracias.

public  class Test2 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
   
   try {
       int n;
       byte[] b = new byte [6];
       System.out.println("Digite los caracteres");
       n = System.in.read(b);
       System.out.println("Número de bytes leídos "+n);
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
       
   } catch (IOException e){
       System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
   }
  
}
```

}

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. Puedes explicarla de otra manera?

Comment: No querrás usar [`nextByte`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextByte())?